# Can I use ASP.NET MVC3 exclusively as a RESTful Web Service?

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-3, sencha-touch

I'm building a READ ONLY [sencha-touch](/questions/tagged/sencha-touch) app for our local church.

We use Vimeo to host all of our videos, and I'd like to integrate our Vimeo vids as well as our RSS feed into our web app.

The rest of the "content" in the app will be static "info" as well as a contact form.

My question is, is it kosher to ONLY use ASP.NET MVC3 (minus the "V") to drive the JSON to our web app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this works great. Just return a JsonResult.

Here is an example I am using in production:

```
 public partial class StudentController : BaseController {
    public StudentController(RESTContext portalContext)
        : base(portalContext) { }

    [HttpGet, Url("organizations/{organizationId?}/students")]
    public virtual JsonResult List(Guid? organizationId) {
        if (organizationId != RESTContext.OrganizationId)
            throw new HttpNotAuthorizedException();

        var query = RESTContext.GetQuery<IQuery<StudentCasesReport>>()
            .Where(x => x.OrganizationId, organizationId)
            .OrderBy(x => x.LastName, SortOrder.Ascending);
        var cases = query.Execute(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);

        return Json(cases, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpGet, Url("organizations/{organizationId?}/students/{studentId?}")]
    public virtual JsonResult Get(Guid? organizationId, Guid? studentId) {
        if (studentId.IsNull())
            throw new HttpNotFoundExecption();

        if (organizationId != RESTContext.OrganizationId)
            throw new HttpNotModifiedException();

        var query = RESTContext.GetQuery<IQuery<StudentCasesReport>>()
            .Where(x => x.OrganizationId, organizationId)
            .Where(x => x.StudentCaseId, studentId)
            .OrderBy(x => x.LastName, SortOrder.Ascending);
        var cases = query.Execute(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted).FirstOrDefault();

        if (cases.IsNull())
            throw new HttpNotFoundExecption();

        return Json(cases, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking. I'm new to web services, so I'm a little concerned about best practices.

Comment: You'll also need to handle 404s and other status codes. MVC3 now gives you the option to return a status code to the user. I would recommend the AttributeRouteMapper project to control routes at the controller level as attributes. Makes it much easier to maintain. http://maproutes.codeplex.com/

Comment: +1 on on this - absolutely. there are those that say go WCF - but my first choice here is always mvc especially since you already have a web app

Comment: Our REST web service code looks very similar. You can go one step further and define a custom action invoker so you can return the model instance instead of JSON result. The invoker can check the Accept header or querystring to determine how to serialize the model.